# Run Spring Batch scheduled by Kubernetes

Tags: spring, kubernetes, cron, spring-batch, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a Spring Batch job and deploy it on Kunernetes. I also use Kubernetes cronjob config to run it daily at 10 AM. Example like this

```
apiVersion: batch/v1

kind: CronJob

metadata:

  name: hello

spec:

  schedule: "0 10 * * *"
```

I concern that if at 10AM, I have 3 pods running, then my job will run 3 times. Does Kubernetes prevents that case, so my job will run only 1 time?

Comment: The CronJob will launch a single new Pod at the indicated time(s).  It's not directly connected to any of your existing Pods.  If the batch job takes more than 24 hours then it's possible there will be more than one copy of it running.  You should be able to observe this behavior deploying these objects in a local environment.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this, you can use the `concurrencyPolicy` field. The `concurrencyPolicy` field can be set to `Allow`, `Forbid`, or `Replace`. If it's set to `Forbid`, the cron job does not allow concurrent jobs, effectively preventing duplicates.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "0 10 * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
```

Comment: Thank for your comment, but I think it not map with my case. concurrencyPolicy: Forbid mean that if it is time for a new job run and the previous job run hasn’t finished yet, the cron job skips the new job run. My concern is that if at 10AM, I have 3 pods running, then my job will concurrently start 3 times (1 time on each pod)